# Unresolved reference inside anonymous Kotlin listener

Tags: android, text-to-speech, kotlin

I have the code below. It is Kotlin. Any idea why `textToSpeech` from `textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK)` is telling that there is no reference resolved for `textToSpeech`?

```
val textToSpeech = TextToSpeech(
            applicationContext,
            object : TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
                override fun onInit(status: Int) {
                    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                        textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK)
                    }
                }

            })
```

At first I assumed it is an Idea kotlin plugin bug, but it seems that it actually can't be compiled

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kotlin has hardened the variables initialization policy, and it's now prohibited to reference the variable inside its initializer, even in lambdas and object expressions, which seems reasonable: imagine that a lambda is called immediately before the variable assignment.

For your case, I can suggest as a workaround using an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) in this quite cumbersome construct:

```
val textToSpeech = object {
    val value: TextToSpeech get() = inner
    private val inner = TextToSpeech(
            applicationContext,
            { value.setLanguage(Locale.UK) }
    )
}.value
```

This will initialize an anonymous object with `inner` inside that is acceptable through `value` property. Note that the `inner` initializer uses `value` property. Then the `value` is extracted and can be used.

But please keep in mind that this trick is unsafe: in runtime, using `value` before `inner` is assigned (e.g. in `TextToSpeech` constructor) will throw `NullPointerException`.

Also, I've replaced the `OnInitListener` with a lambda using [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) to be short, but object expression can still be used there.

---

**UPD:** check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100389/writing-a-kotlin-util-function-which-provides-self-reference-in-initializer) for my effort to generalize this approach. Using it, you can write

```
val textToSpeech = selfReference {
    TextToSpeech(
        applicationContext,
        { self.setLanguage(Locale.UK) }
    )
}
```

See the [sources on Github](https://github.com/h0tk3y/kotlin-fun/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/github/h0tk3y/kotlinFun/SelfReference.kt).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very readable and clear way to face that problem. First you should define this:

```
fun <T> selfReferenced(initializer: () -> T) = initializer.invoke()
operator fun<T> T.getValue(any: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) = this
```

and later use

```
val valueName: ValueType by selfReferenced{
    //here you can create and use the valueName object
}
```

Using your problem as example you can do:

```
val textToSpeech:TextToSpeech by selfReferenced {
TextToSpeech(
        applicationContext,
        TextToSpeech.OnInitListener { status ->
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK)
            }
        })
    }
```

Inside the selfReferenced block you can use the outer object with no restrictions. The only thing you should take care of, is declaring the type explicitly to avoid recursive type checking issues.