# Variable 'runnable' must be initialized

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Why does Kotlin complains about this:

```
class MyActivity : Activity {
  private var handler:Handler = Handler()

  private var runnable: Runnable = Runnable {
    /* Do something very important */
    handler.postDelayed(this@MyActivity.runnable, 5000)
  }
}
```

Compiler complains that `Variable 'runnable' must be initialized` in the Line were it's posted again by handler.
This does work in plain Java:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
    }
};
```

Comment: Aren't you concerned about it being a cyclical reference or something?

Comment: Should I be? The idea behind it that this Runnable should be executed each 5s. Or am I missing something very obvious?!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Kotlin considers a property uninitialized until the end of its initializer, therefore it cannot be used inside its own initializer, even in lambdas. This semantics is similar to the limitation of [local variable usage inside its initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049850/unresolved-reference-inside-anonymous-kotlin-listener/35050722#35050722).

There are several workarounds:

- Use [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) which lets you reference `this` of the declared object:

  ```
  private var runnable: Runnable = object : Runnable {
      override fun run() {
          /* Do something very important */
          handler.postDelayed(this, 5000)
      }
  }
  ```

  This works well only for interfaces as a replacement for lambdas and is not very pretty altogether.
- Use [`lateinit var`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) or a [delegated property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) with [`Delegates.notNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/not-null.html):

  ```
  private lateinit var runnable: Runnable
  init {
      runnable = Runnable { 
          /* Do something very important */
          handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000)
      }
  }
  ```

  The same initializer will work with this declaration:

  ```
  private var runnable: Runnable by Delegates.notNull()
  ```
- Implement and use [self-reference for initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100389/writing-a-kotlin-util-function-which-provides-self-reference-in-initializer) on your own:

  ```
  class SelfReference<T>(val initializer: SelfReference<T>.() -> T) {
      val self: T by lazy {
          inner ?: throw IllegalStateException("Do not use `self` until initialized.")
      }

      private val inner = initializer()
  }

  fun <T> selfReference(initializer: SelfReference<T>.() -> T): T {
      return SelfReference(initializer).self
  }
  ```

  And then you can write something like

  ```
  private var runnable: Runnable = selfReference { 
      Runnable {
          /* Do something very important */
          handler.postDelayed(self, 5000)
      } 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
private var runnable: Runnable = Runnable {
    /* Do something very important */
    handler.postDelayed(runnable(), 5000)
}

private fun runnable() = runnable
```

Comment: Instead of a function you could also use a read-only property:
`private val runnableCopy get() = runnable`