# UNINITIALIZED_VARIABLE Variable _longPressed must be inistialized

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Handler and Runnable, when runnable execute I need to remove callback from my handler.

If I do that, with that way

```
private val _handler = Handler()

private val _longPressed: Runnable = Runnable {
    _handler.removeCallbacks(_longPressed)
}
```

compile time error happens with error UNINITIALIZED_VARIABLE

and if I move the removeCallBacks method to the function, the error is gone,I'm interesting, what is the difference?

```
private val _longPressed: Runnable = Runnable {
    removeRunnable()
}

fun removeRunnable(){
    _handler.removeCallbacks(_longPressed)
}
```

Comment: Can you post the declaration of `_handler` variable?

Comment: ok, I have updated my question

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili I'm quite not sure **_longPressed** is not yet assigned when using under Runnable. But in java we use **this** try like that

Comment: Agree with @Raghavendra, using `this` should solve the problem. as `this` inside `Runnable` refers to `_longPressed` basically

Comment: keyword this will be the Activity and Type mismatch compile time error will appear

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. If you declare runnable as `object : Runnable {...}` and implement the `run` method, there you can reference that `Runnable` with `this`.

Answer (score 1):

At compile time while doing the `_longPressed` variable assignment, it first evaluates the Runnable code (value of the variable) . Since on this case `_longPressed` doesn't exist, it throws the compilation error.

On the later case, while evaluating the Runnable code at compile time, it just knows that it has to call an existent function `removeRunnable` which references a variable that exists on the class (_longPressed).

Comment: yes, I think so, but is it ok? Is there any chance when runnable code block will be executed _longPressed may be uninitialized?

Comment: No because the runnable code block will be already assigned to the _longPressed variable right after instantiating the class where it is contained

Comment: than it doesn't make sense, for showing that error yes?

Comment: It shows the error because kotlin looks for variable self reference when making assignments due to the fact that you could be calling this same variable just before the assignment is finished. It doesn't discriminate when it will be called, it just doesn't let you do it. Check the duplicate answer referenced and also another [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049850/unresolved-reference-inside-anonymous-kotlin-listener/35050722#35050722) referenced in that answer